# Building a reactive long polling API with webflux

Tags: spring-mvc, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, long-polling

I'm trying to use spring webflux to build a reactive long-polling API service, I have implemented a service that produces a data stream from my data resource(Kafka). And the caller of this long-polling API is supposed to get/wait for the first data with the requested key. But somehow the API is not returning the data if data received after the application gets the data. Am I using the correct reactor methods? Thanks so much!

My service:

```
@Service 
public class KafkaService {
    // the processor is a in-memory cache that keeps tracking of the old messages
    @Autowired private KafkaMessageProcessor kafkaMessageProcessor;
      @Autowired private ApplicationEventService applicationEventService;  
    private Flux<KafkaMessage> eventFlux;

    @PostConstruct
     public void setEventFlux() {
         this.eventFlux = Flux.create(applicationEventService).share(); 
    }

    public Flux<KafkaMessage> listenToKeyFlux(String key) {     
        return kafkaMessageProcessor
             .getAll()
             .concatWith(this.eventFlux.share())
             .filter(x -> x.getKey().equals(key)); }
}
```

My handler:

```
@RestController
 @RequestMapping("/longpolling") 
public class LongPollingController {
      private static final String MSG_PREFIX = "key_";
      @Autowired private KafkaService kafkaService;

    @GetMapping("/message/{key}")
     @CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*", origins = "*")
     public CompletableFuture<KafkaMessage> getMessage(@PathVariable String key) {      
        return kafkaService.listenToKeyFlux(MSG_PREFIX + key).shareNext().toFuture();
     }
}
```